# PHP OOP Call to a member function on a non-object driving me nuts

Tags: php, oop

I'm currently programming a script to list all teams in my database, within the list will be the teams payment info I have two functions which care called for when displaying the data. The code is use it below:

```
          $teams = $teams->team_list();
          foreach ($teams as $team) {

          $payments = $teams->fetch_team_payment_info($team['team_id']);
           echo $team['team_id'];
          }
```

The $team->team_list() works without any errors and does what it is suppose to however the

```
          $payments = $teams->fetch_team_payment_info($team_id);
```

Does not.

I have correctly set the $teams class using the code below:

```
    $teams = new teams($g8b_db);
    $teams->entryYear = $system->get_entry_year();

    class teams {
        private $db; 
        public $entryYear;

        public function __construct(Database $db) {
            $this->db = $db;
        }

        public function team_list() {
            $sql = "SELECT td.*, CONCAT(me.First_Name,' ', me.Surname) AS managers_full_name, me.Telephone AS managers_telephone  
            FROM `team_details` td 
            JOIN `members` me 
            ON me.id = td.managers_user_id 
            WHERE td.entry_year = '" . $this->entryYear. "'";
            $registered_teams = $this->db->fetch_all_array($sql);
            return $registered_teams;
        }

        public function fetch_team_payment_info($team_id) {
            $fetch_payments = $this->db->fetch_array_assoc($this->db->query("SELECT `method`, `account_holder`, `date` FROM `payments` WHERE `team_id`='".$team_id."'"));
            $team = $this->db->fetch_all_array("SELECT `status` FROM `team_details` WHERE `team_id`='".$team_id."'");

            if ($team['status']=="0") {
                $status_text = "Marked As Unpaid";
            } elseif ($team['status']=="1") {
                $status_text = "Marked As Paid";
            } elseif ($team['status']=="2") {
                $status_text = "Rejected";
            }

            $payment_method             =     $fetch_payments['method'];
            $payment_account_holder     =     $fetch_payments['account_holder'];
            $payment_date               =     $fetch_payments['date'];
            $payment_text = "".$payment_method." by ".$payment_account_holder." on ".$payment_date."";

            if ($payment_method == "Paypal") {
                $label_end_payment = "primary"; 
            } 
            if ($payment_method == "Bank Transfer") {
                $label_end_payment = "info"; 
            }

            $payment_label = '<a class="label label-'.$label_end_payment.'" data-placement="bottom" tabindex="0" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Payment Method" data-content="'.$payment_text.'">'.$payment_method.'</a>';

            $data = array(
                'payment_label'          => $payment_text,
                'status'                 => $status_text
            );
            return $data;
        }
        }
```

I can not understand why this error would be displaying if team_list is working.

Any help to shed some light on the issue would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I do not see foreach loop in your code sample, and in the first snippet of code you are referring to $teams; are your trying to refer to current class this way ? if so do $this->fetch_team_payment_info($team_id);

Comment: Where `$team_id` comes from? it seems like you don't change it anywhere in the cycle.

Comment: My bad $team_id is actually $team['team_id']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've reassigned $teams in a loop.

`team_list()` does not return "teams" class, so you get an error.

There is many ways to fix it, here is one of them:

```
foreach ($teams->team_list() as $team) {
  $payments = $teams->fetch_team_payment_info($team_id);
  echo $team['team_id'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, such a simple mistake. Not sure why you have been marked as un useful when you are correct!